# BarPlot3D box inclusion of Graphics3D primitives

Tags: plotting

My final goal is to get coordinate grid on the `z=0` plane of `BarChart3D`. The provided `FaceGrid` is not suitable as it would be below the lowest bar.

I tried to do draw the grid using graphics primitives but I failed to get desired result. The surrounding box tries to include my tick labels and it does not look so good. Here my minimal example:

```
ρ = 1/2 ( {
     {1, 0, 0, -1},
     {0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0},
     {-1, 0, 0, 1}
    } );

Show[{
  BarChart3D[ρ,
   Boxed -> True,
   BarSpacing -> {1, 1},
   ChartLayout -> "Grid",
   FaceGrids -> None,
   Axes -> {True, True, True},
   ViewPoint -> {1, -5, 3},
   Method -> {"Canvas" -> None},
   Ticks -> {
     Range[-10, 10, 2],
     Range[-10, 10, 2],
     Range[-10, 10, 2]
     }
   ],
  Graphics3D[{
    Table[Text[y, {10, y 2 - 1.5, 0}], {y, 1, 4}],
    Table[Line[{{-4, y 2 - 1.5, 0}, {10, y 2 - 1.5, 0}}], {y, 1, 4}]
    }]
  }]
```

[image: BarChart3D with bad box]

What I want is the plot labels outside of the surrounding box, not inside. The funny thing is, that for example `ListPlot3D` there is no such effect and thus there is something in `Graphics3D` which I do not understand. Let me give an example:

```
Show[{
  ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 8}, {-1, 8}, {-0.5, 0.5}},
   Boxed -> True,
   FaceGrids -> None,
   Axes -> {True, True, True},
   ViewPoint -> {1, -5, 3},
   Ticks -> {
     Range[-10, 10, 2],
     Range[-10, 10, 2],
     Range[-10, 10, 2]
     }],
  BarChart3D[ρ,
   BarSpacing -> {1, 1},
   ChartLayout -> "Grid",
   FaceGrids -> None,
   Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}
   ],
  Graphics3D[{
    Table[Text[y, {10, y 2 - 1.5, 0}], {y, 1, 4}],
    Table[Line[{{-4, y 2 - 1.5, 0}, {10, y 2 - 1.5, 0}}], {y, 1, 4}]
    }]
  }]
```

[image]

- Why does `ListPlot3D` and `BarChart3D` act differently,
- how to get the elements out of surrounding box in more clean way than wrapping it with `ListPlot3D` and
- perhaps there is a more elegant way to get "cityline bar charts" with `z=0` plane coordinate grid & ticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When combining objects with `Show`, the option that was specified first will be used for the entire display, unless it is overridden in the options to `Show` itself. Now look at the `PlotRange` option specifically for the two objects `BarChart3D` and `ListPlot3D` that you created (I give them individual names here):

```
bc = 
  BarChart3D[ρ, Boxed -> True, BarSpacing -> {1, 1}, 
   ChartLayout -> "Grid", FaceGrids -> None, 
   Axes -> {True, True, True}, ViewPoint -> {1, -5, 3}, 
   Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, 
   Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10, 2], Range[-10, 10, 2], Range[-10, 10, 2]}];

lp = 
  ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 8}, {-1, 8}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, Boxed -> True, 
   FaceGrids -> None, Axes -> {True, True, True}, 
   ViewPoint -> {1, -5, 3}, 
   Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10, 2], Range[-10, 10, 2], Range[-10, 10, 2]}];

Options[bc, PlotRange]

(* ==> {PlotRange -> All} *)

Options[lp, PlotRange]

(* ==> {PlotRange -> {{-1, 8}, {-1, 8}, {-0.5, 0.5}}} *)
```

The `BarChart3D` has the option set to `All`, which we don't want. By adding the `ListPlot3D` as the first element in `Show`, you simply override that setting with the last line.

This immediately tells us how to get the same effect without adding the empty `ListPlot3D`: just specify the desired limited `PlotRange` in `BarChart3D`:

```
Show[{BarChart3D[ρ, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 8}, {-1, 8}, {-0.5`, 0.5`}}, Boxed -> True, 
   BarSpacing -> {1, 1}, ChartLayout -> "Grid", FaceGrids -> None, 
   Axes -> {True, True, True}, ViewPoint -> {1, -5, 3}, 
   Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, 
   Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10, 2], Range[-10, 10, 2], 
     Range[-10, 10, 2]}], 
  Graphics3D[{Table[Text[y, {10, y 2 - 1.5, 0}], {y, 1, 4}], 
    Table[Line[{{-4, y 2 - 1.5, 0}, {10, y 2 - 1.5, 0}}], {y, 1, 
      4}]}]}]
```

[image: barchart3d]

Comment: Damn. I spent 5 hours on this thing and in the end it turned out to be difference in default values. Thanks!